# how to disable vertical auto-centering of cursor

Tags: customize

I recently had my Ubuntu Linux upgraded to 14.04, and my emacs got upgraded to 24.3.1 in the process. I noticed that it scrolls by itself. I finally realized that it automatically centers the cursor vertically after a few seconds. This is extremely annoying to me. I decided to give it a try for an hour or so to see if I can get used to it, but it still annoys me. I went to the options menu, but I see nothing about that feature. Can anyone tell me how to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: That's definitely something in your init file. I remember trying this feature too. If memory serves, it was implemented as a minor mode, so to identify it, press `C-h m` and look at the description of minor modes you have enabled, most likely it will be there somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with `emacs -Q` first and see if the problem still exists (it should not).  Then bisect your init file to figure out what causes it.

I'm using `centered-cursor-mode` as a global minor mode to keep the cursor vertically centered, but it behaves somewhat differently than what you describe.  Your best bet is to bisect your init file (comment half of it and concentrate on the half that appears to be responsible, then repeat on that half until you are at the line that causes the undesired behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10337/emacs-sometimes-starts-automatically-recentering-cursor-position/10339#10339) to a similar question.

Try killing any buffer-list buffer.

Comment: Yes, when I kill my buffer list the problem ceases. That's progress. But how am I supposed to work without a buffer list? I use that constantly. Also, I see that the problem is not fixed in the next version. Is it finally fixed now, or do I need to go back to an earlier version (if so, which)? What a clusterf**k!

Comment: This answer is a link to an answer that is also a link. Could you either expand the answer here so that it stands alone, or, if this is a duplicate, mark it as such?

Comment: I took the liberty of marking this a duplicate. Answering your question, @RussP., this was indeed fixed in 24.4 (which was released last year). Ubuntu takes a long while to update its official packages, but I'm sure there's a way to install 24.4 from the ubuntu package manager (try googling a bit).

Comment: I installed 24.4.1 and that solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well, my assessment was premature. I am still having this problem even in 24.4.1. This is rapidly becoming a huge waste of time for me. Moreover, I don't understand how such a major bug could have persisted for this long. Doesn't everyone use the buffer list? If not, how do you select buffers and directories?

Comment: I finally tracked it down to this line: (setq global-auto-revert-non-file-buffers 0)